# Efficient conversion of Float32Array(3) arrays to Vector3 and back

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D model whose vertices are defined like this:

```
let positions=[[15.85415005683899,27.896950021386147,-24.917999282479286],[16.001449897885323,29.114199802279472,-24.810049682855606], ...];
```

As I am new to JavaScript (and have a background in C programming) I may be mistaken, but I believe that `[]` stands for an array in JavaScript so effectively  `[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0][4.0, 5.0, 6.0],...] I believe is an array of an array of 3 floats.

Next, I do have a function that is processing the vertices. The function needs to return an array that is as big as the size of the vertex array. Initially, I was using the [gl-Matrix library](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/blob/master/src/vec3.js) to process the vertices. This was "simple" because, in gl-Matrix, 3-dimensional vectors are also stored as an array of 3 numbers, like so:

```
export function create()
{
    let out = new Float32Array(3);
    out[0] = out[1] = out[2] = 0;
    return out;
}
```

So the function to process the vertices looked likes this:

```
function doSomething(positions)
{
    const outputs = positions.map(() => {
        return [0, 0, 0];
    });

    outputs.forEach((e, index) => {
        // add: e = e + position (add(out, a, b))
        add(e, e, positions[index])
    });
    return outputs;
}
```

What the function does is not relevant (I simplified it for the question). But it does 2 things that I am after: it seems to "resize" the outputs array to the dimension of the input array (position) and set the elements with a default value along the way, and in the second block, as the gl-Matrix library defines the 3D vector as an array of 3 floats, it's compatible with the format the 3D vectors are defined into, in the input array (positions). So all is well.

Now I discovered a bit later the `three.js` library in which [3D Vectors](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Vector3.js) are defined using a class:

```
class Vector3
{
    constructor( x = 0, y = 0, z = 0 ) {

        Vector3.prototype.isVector3 = true;

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;

    }
   ...
}
```

I decided to use this class. But now my function becomes:

```
function doSomething(positions)
{
    const outputs= [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; ++i) {
        outputs.push(new Vector3(0,0,0));
    }

    outputs.forEach((o, index) => {
        const p = positions[index];
        o.add(new Vector3(p[0], p[1], p[2]));
    });
    return outputs;
}
```

The way I managed to create an array of the needed size, was to loop over all elements in positions and push a new `Vector3()` to the `outputs` array. In the second block, as the elements in the positions array are not in a format that's compatible with the `Vector3` type, I need to create a `Vector3` on the fly and set it with the values of the element from the positions array corresponding to the current index.

Questions):

- Is it possible to dynamically allocate the size of the `outputs` array directly? Without going through the iteration and the push? Looping over the element and pushing a new one on the stack doesn't feel efficient.
- Is it possible to avoid the conversation from `Float32Array(3)` to `Vector3`? This is a *"time critical app"* so the less time I waste copying data, the better. I can also add that I am stuck with storing the position data as an array of 3 floats. Can I store the elements in a way that's immediately mappable to the type `Vector3`?

I come from the `C` world in which these aspects are rather trivial (you can treat data stored in an array as a raw float array of numbers, for example, assuming, of course, that memory is contiguous and elements are stored linearly). Being new to JS, I am not sure what's the best way of doing this in the language. While the functions above are simplified for the sake of the question, they are more complicated in practice and thus it feels like if I could come up with a better way, the app would gain in efficiency (especially as I have to load the data later back from `Vector3` to an array of 3 floats `Float32Array(3)`. Help from the JS gurus out there would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First thing to understand is that JavaScript *typed* arrays (like `Float32Array`) are similar to, but *distinctly different from*, ordinary JavaScript arrays. There's no reason to pre-allocate a plain array in JavaScript. Setting something on `Vector3.prototype` in the constructor makes no sense; that only needs to be set once when the class is created.

Comment: @Pointy  Yeah, that prototype assign in the constructor makes no sense, but it's actually in three.js code.. :o

Comment: @Pointy. Thanks for your comment. I have to say I am not the one who designed the `three.js` `vec3.js` lib and I don't know the reason why they added this line. Again I am new to JS. So it seems from what you say that pre-allocating arrays in JS is not something that would be done (is the only option to push elements?). Is there any impact performance wise? (I assume it works like the `std::vector` in C++?).

Comment: To pre-allocate an array in JS is `const arr = new Array(size)`, and then to fill it's just `arr[x] = something`  If this has any performance improvements on just doing `arr.push()` or not even calling `new Array(size)` and just doing `arr[x] = ` from the bat,  you would need to test.

Comment: @Keith ok well ... uhh, that's a thing to know I guess.